Snowflake Notebook- how to achieve parallelism?
As i know that when executing snowflake notebook through its scheduler, it execute each cell one by one as sequential model.
however i want to paralyze the process where all cell - suppose i have 3 copy operation resides in 3 cell should executed parallelly without waiting to complete previous cell execution.
I don't want to use any third party tool such as airflow to orchestrate from outside snowflake  and want to achieve within snowflake.
Is there any possibility available currently with snowflake to achieve parallelism?

The only way to achieve parallelism in Snowflake (ignoring possibly complex coding solutions) is to get tasks to run in parallel. So you would need a notebook structure where tasks could execute just the commands that you want to run in parallel

you mean using single notebook which accept copy command dynamically from a 3 task can achieve this? @NickW

Try the multiprocess package. See parallel processing - Python Simple Loop Parallelization Jupyter Notebook - Stack Overflow for an example.

Probably not what I meant. If you don’t want to go down the route of the type of code solution that @DaveWelden is suggesting, the only way to achieve parallelism is to have a parent task with child tasks and then the child tasks run in parallel. Within this framework, you would need to work out what each child task needs to run and then construct the rest of your solution around this. So if a task can only run a whole notebook then you would need the code you want to run in parallel in separate notebooks
